# PID 4 Using Port 80 - IIS Unable To Bind

Tags: port, iis, netstat

So I've been having a problem where I can't use localhost:80 on IIS

So I ran this:

```
> netstat -ano | find "0:80"
```

And got:

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
```

I then looked under the details tab of Task Manager and PID 4 is "System".
I have no clue what this is or what it does...

Help please?

Answer (score 2):

So after doing a load of research, the fix that worked for me was as follows:

Run: services.msc

Find "Windows Sync Share"

Stop it if running, and set it's startup to disabled.

IIS can now bind to localhost:80

I have see no side effects of stopping the process either.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. So many different answers on the web. This one worked for me.
Windows Server 2019