# IIS 8 / Windows Server 2012 R2 - PID 4 using Port 443

Tags: port, iis, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8

So I had an issue a little while ago with port 80 being used by PID 4.
But I solved this issue [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1078775/pid-4-using-port-80-iis-unable-to-bind).

But now I'm trying to setup a binding to localhost 443 in IIS and again it can't do it.

Ran the commands the same as last time with port 80, and again it is PID 4 using it, but I can't work out what and my research has produced nothing.

Any ideas what I need to disable to get localhost:443 free from PID 4?

Comment: Are you using Work Folders? [Windows Server 2012 R2 – Resolving Port Conflict with IIS Websites and Work Folders](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/filecab/2013/10/15/windows-server-2012-r2-resolving-port-conflict-with-iis-websites-and-work-folders/)

Comment: Some other possibilities: [Why is the System process listening on Port 443?](http://superuser.com/q/125455)

Comment: @DavidPostill I disabled Sync Share for my port 80 issue, and read through that other post, but nothing in there helps.

Comment: When using IIS on Windows, Port 80 and possible 443 are suppose to be used by PID 4, because PID 4 is the system itself, and IIS is listening on ports using the kernel mode driver `http.sys`. Kernel mode drivers are "running" in process with ID 4. So all is normal. You have to explain what you actual problem is.

Comment: @PeterHahndorf I cannot bind a site to localhost:443 in IIS. That is my problem. (As stated in my question)